# Check if computers from file are online

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to check if computer from file computers.txt are online or not. I'm using below commend but i would like to see computer name next to true or false resolution of this. It its possible to add it?

```
Test-Connection -BufferSize 32 -Count 1 -ComputerName (Get-Content C:\Temp\computers.txt) -Quiet |
Out-GridView
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alternative to Theo's answer, using [Select-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7) syntax:

```
Get-Content C:\Temp\computers.txt |
select @{n="Computer";e={$_}}, @{n="IsOnline";e={Test-Connection -BufferSize 32 -Count 1 -ComputerName $_ -Quiet}} |
Out-GridView
```

**Pros**: Faster, and works even with older PowerShell versions that do not support `[pscustomobject]`

**Cons**: Clumsy syntax

Answer (score 3):

To do that you need to use a ForEach loop and output a PSObject with the properties you want:

```
Get-Content C:\Temp\computers.txt | ForEach-Object {
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        Computer = $_
        IsOnline = Test-Connection -BufferSize 32 -Count 1 -ComputerName $_ -Quiet
    }
} | Out-GridView
```